# tomar datos de un formulario con angular?

Tags: html5, angular

por ejemplo tengo en un componente llamado barra de busqueda

```
<form>
<input type="text" name ="buscar"><br>
<input type="submit" value=buscar>
</form>
```

dentro de ese componente hay un barra.components.ts que seria el codigo typescript de mi componente como puedo obtener los datos de mi formulario de busqueda en el codigo ts que esta en el mismo componente?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PokeServiceService } from 'src/app/services/poke-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  stats: any;

  constructor( private pokeService: PokeServiceService ) { }

  getPokemon(pokemon: string): void {
   this.pokeService.getPokemon(pokemon);
   console.log(pokemon);
   this.stats = this.pokeService.stats;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza ngModel

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PokeServiceService } from 'src/app/services/poke-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  stats: any;
  form: any = {
    name: ""
  }

  constructor( private pokeService: PokeServiceService ) { }

  getPokemon(pokemon: string): void {
   this.pokeService.getPokemon(pokemon);
   console.log(pokemon);
   this.stats = this.pokeService.stats;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  send(){
    console.log(this.form); //Aqui deberia imprimir todos los datos del formulario
  }

}
```

```html
<form (submit)="send()">
   <input type="text" name ="buscar" [(ngModel)]="form.name"><br>
   <input type="submit" value=buscar>
</form>
```

Comment: y como puedo llamarlo en el ts?

Comment: El evento submit se ejecuta cuando le das click al <input type="submit" value=buscar> y automaticamente se ejecuta el metodo send. Despues podrias llamar a tu metodo getPokemon o incluso llamar al metodo directamente en el formulario en vez del metodo send

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar los formularios reactivos que vienen en Angular, te dejo el link a la documentación oficial con un ejemplo:

https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms